# Selenium - Decorated WebDriver sends keys without focus on input element (placeholder text still present)

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, firefox

## Problem - works only on local env

**Goal:** Focus on element, enter keys, lose focus (focus on body)
**Issue:** Input element has placeholder AND entered value.
**Environment**: It works locally but fails on linux geckodriver's (v0.32) headless browser installed via docker image
**Note**: it was rather stable on previous version of selenium - 4.0 and not decorated WebDriver but same issue happened from time to time. Right now it always happens.

### Steps to reproduce:

**Setup**: Java 8, Selenium 4.4.0, Linux system, headless Firefox

1. Initialize **Decorated** WebDriver - `new CustomEventFiringDecorator<>(...).decorate(driver)` ***[1]***
2. Navigations etc...
3. Find input element
4. Click to focus
5. Enter keys ***[2]***
6. Click body to lose focus (this triggers form's fields validation)

## Things I've tried

- Clicking via: WebDriver, WebElement, Actions, JavaScript
- Setting focus to element and body with JS

---

**[1]** *CustomEventFiringDecorator is almost plain copy of EventFiringDecorator, but I needed different onError implementation*
**[2]** Previously sent via WebElement (same issue) Currently:

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
        for (char letter : text.toCharArray()) {
            actions.sendKeys(element, String.valueOf(letter));
            actions.pause(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        }
        actions.build().perform();
```

Comment: the sendKeys method will automatically set focus...  (no need to use actions... just element.sendKeys...) to lose focus you can probably just send keys of Keys.TAB.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks, but already been doing that including the TAB key, I don't suppose anything around sending keys or setting focus will help since everything works on local, I'm *probably* looking for a solution that involves either decorated webdriver or environment setup change

Comment: make sure the 2 versions of Selenium and driver(s) match.  I think at some point they switched from WebDriverEventListener to EventFiringDecorator.  Your error (or lack of? nothing happens??) might also be caused by your event listeners which you don't show.  Maybe include whatever code is related to the EventFiringDecorator.  Did the events fire correctly on local?  Does it work local using headless?

Comment: @pcalkins they actually did, yes, I worked through it and events actually fire pretty nicely. It does work with headless on local.   
**So** - right about now I switched to newer version of selenium, updated my driver capabilities and problem *seems* to be gone - I'm still testing it, but apparently nothing is wrong with Decorated WebDriver but rather the setup, but I can't figure what was causing such severe problem.

Comment: ok it only seemed to be gone, it's still there, nothing helps I guess.. 

Answer (score 0):

Updating firefox version worked